# Is GCM device id will expiry, If so How to solve this for android

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I was doing register for the device for push notification, we have received device id then i pushed to server through API call. After some time it will expires in server. How to solve this

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Then try to store that device Id in your DB.

Answer (score 0):

A fairly standard approach is the register your device with GCM **every time your app starts**.  You will then receive a GMC token which you can use for push notifications.

Doing this at every app startup may seem redundant, but it solves the problem of replacing an expired token.  Most of the time, GCM will simply return a token that is the same as the one your app already has.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910803/register-a-device-on-gcm-every-time-the-app-start-is-the-right-approach/20910980#20910980) for more details.

Comment: Does this answer your question?