# is GCM's token id a good substitution for device's uuid?

Tags: android

In my app I need to identify each installation and user. Currently I'm generating my uuid with a combination of Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID, sim serial and build serial for that purpose. Recently, I've been working on integrating google cloud message into my app. now in my database there seems to be 2 ids for each installation. Is it a good idea to use GCM's token id to replace my current device id? which one is more reliable? assuming google service is present on every installation.

Comment: IIRC, the GCM token id can change at any time. Not sure how that affects your thinking on this topic.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest against using the GCM token token ID as an identifier for the application or user or device.  The main reason is that Google makes no guarantee that it will stay the same for a given device.  Thus it is possible that Google may even re-cycle these IDs at some point - although unlikely, there is nothing in the GCM documentation that says this will not happen.

It is generally considered a good idea to re-register your device with GCM periodically: (see [Register a device on GCM every time the app start is the right approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910803/register-a-device-on-gcm-every-time-the-app-start-is-the-right-approach/20910980#20910980)).  This makes it more likely that eventually your app's GCM token *might* change.  Again, the GCM docs make no promises that it will always stay the same for a given device.

If you need to uniquely identify an app installation, here is a good, well-thought approach: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/03/identifying-app-installations.html.

Finally a word of warning about your approach.  If I read it correctly, you are using the SIM card ID in some way.  Keep in mind that this will not be present in all devices (e.g. tablets).

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest that you should keep gcm id and device id in separate column, both have different-different role for purpose. GCM Id will be useful for notification purpose and the best way is why don't you update GCM id each time whenever a user requests for gcm id from gcm server. 
And for more output you must use GCM class's property properly. Here is required code.

```
public class GCMIntentService extends GCMBaseIntentService{

    String value11,value22,value33,value44;
    static String msg;
    static Bitmap myBitmap,myBitmapy;
    String arr[];
    static String ns;
    static NotificationManager myNotiMgr;
    static Context cgh;
    String type;
    static String GOOGLE_SENDER_ID  ="124545124542";
    private static final String TAG = "GCMIntentService";

    public GCMIntentService() 
    {
        super(GOOGLE_SENDER_ID);
    }


    protected void onRegistered(Context context, String registrationId) 
    {

        try 
        {

            cgh=context;
            Log.d("vddddddd",cgh+""+registrationId);
            TelephonyManager tmw = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            String imeie = tmw.getDeviceId();
            new HttpAsynctask1().execute("http://url);



        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();


        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onUnregistered(Context context, String registrationId) 
    {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String  link    =   "";

        try{
             type = intent.getStringExtra("price");
             Log.d("msgggg",type);
             generateNotification(context, type);

        }
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDeletedMessages(Context context, int total) 
    {


    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Context context, String errorId) 
    {

    }

}
```

Thank you.