# "Registration" for an ionic3 app using phonegap-push-plugin

Tags: push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I developed an ionic3 app that uses phonegap-push-plugin in order to recive  push-notifications.

Does anyone knows how many time do I have to call "registration" like this

```
pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));
```

a) Do I have to make a "registration" every time I open my app?

b) Or is enought only once after first installing the app?

... and why ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [Register a device on GCM every time the app start is the right approach?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20910803/register-a-device-on-gcm-every-time-the-app-start-is-the-right-approach)
the answer is:
1. Every time the app is updated
2. When the phone restarts

Is it possible, beside these 2 cases, to have a third namely "when OS is updated"?